# Parse pointer in JSON file are blank after import

Tags: json, pointers, parse-platform, objectid

first time poster here.

I uploaded a JSON file to Parse, one of my "columns" is an array of Pointers, but it's not pointing to the objectId field, like so:

```
{ "Tags": [
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "TAGS_Categories",
            "TAGS": "Tag1"
        },
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "TAGS_Categories",
            "TAGS": "Tag2"
        },
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "TAGS_Categories",
            "TAGS": "Tag3"
        }
    ]
}
```

But after I imported the file to Parse, this is what appears under "Tags":

```
[{},{},{}]
```

My questions are: 
1) is the data somehow hidden and it's just not appearing on the website's spreadsheet? 
2) if it's truly gone, what would the best way to fix my JSON file so that it will appear?

Help :-(

Comment: Why is your JSON not pointing to the objectId then ?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to have pointers go to the actual names of the Tags, as opposed to the objectId which much more difficult to work with.

Comment: Difficult from a human standpoint but required by the machine overlords who actually process your JSON...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When uploading content you need to follow the required data format. Pointers are connected by a combination of the class name and the object id for the item to connect to. Without the object id the item in the data store can't be found (a name lookup will not be performed).

You need to update your JSON payload to include the object ids.

Each item must have the fields:

```
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"XXXX","objectId":"YYYYYYYYYY"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wain, I ended up changing the "TAGS_Categories" so that the objectIds were the same as the "TAGS."